# is WinRT a virtual environment to run Application?

Tags: windows-runtime, virtual-machine, bytecode

I'd like to know whether applications designed for WinRT are run within a Virtual Machine or compiled in bytecode in order to be compiled once and run everywhere as the slogan says.

Answer (score 1):

The slogan isn't that. WinRT apps rely on COM for runtime cross-environment calls and a metadata format (winmd) to describe the types.

A WinRT app can be fully native (as is most/all of the framework and even the XAML engine).

Individual DLLs or the app itself could be written in a .NET language, and it will interop almost seamlessly with the rest of WinRT thanks to the extended interop code added to the CLR. Under the hood, it's mostly COM interop as usual, but with added "projections" of chosen WinRT types. This is what makes a WinRT IVector look like an IList in .NET. They're just automatically wrapped.

The strength of WinRT is the binary method calling abstraction of COM and the metadata system (without which the language "projections" wouldn't exist). But it is definitely native, just like COM is, and you can stay in C++ without revving up the .NET CLR if you like.

Comment: For anyone curious about how the CLR interacts with WinRT, you can dig around http://referencesource.microsoft.com to find many bits and pieces (see e.g. "mscorlib").

Comment: Thanks, does that mean when an application is developped for WinRT it is    compiled/cross-compiled at least twice:
- One binary for Smartphone (arm arch)
- Another binary for x86

Comment: Correct. Although WP has used a slightly different set of platform libraries, (called "WinPRT") and it has meant a small amount of porting necessary to build for them both.

Comment: The difference is said to be eliminated by Windows 10.